# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al editar una variable en un JQuery Sql server, se edite en todas las líneas donde se encuentra?

Tags: sql, jquery, base-de-datos, línea-de-comandos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que al momento de seleccionar el número especificado en la variable "SecuenciaVenta" este se edite en las líneas que están más abajo al mismo tiempo, no se si exista una combinación de teclas y/o deba cambiarse alguna configuración.